# Bhargava’s proof of van der Waerden conjecture: how to use Hilbert irreducibility to show almost all polynomials have Galois group $S_n$

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

On the first page of [his paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2111.06507.pdf) where he proves van der Waerden’s conjecture, Bhargava mentions that Hilbert’s irreducibility theorem shows that the number of monic integer polynomials of degree $n$, all of whose coefficients have absolute value less than $H$, which have Galois group not equal to $S_n$ is $o(H^n)$. I suppose the argument he’s referring to is well-known or straightforward, although he does not cite a source. What is the argument?

Answer (score 3):

The argument is old, going back to van der Waerden, with improvements by later authors such as Gallagher.  See [here](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Ewdduke/preprints/probabilistic.pdf) (look for the notation $E_n(N)$) and Theorem 1.2 [here](https://surim.stanford.edu/sites/g/files/sbiybj9281/f/projects/irreducibility_and_galois_groups_of_random_polynomials_hanson_hao_eli_navarro_henri_stern.pdf).

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I will accept the answer once I have a chance to read the sources you linked.

Comment: The paper of van der Waerden is mentioned on the MSE page https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2071358/making-precise-generally-the-galois-group-is-s-n. Note the German terms “mit Affekte” (with Affect) and “ohne Affekt” (without Affect) refer to a degree-$n$ equation having Galois group $S_n$ or Galois group smaller than $S_n$. I do not know what “Affekt” is really meaning literally here (why being “with it” means all permutation appear in the Galois group).

Comment: @KCd I think you've got it backwards: "ohne Affekt" means Galois group $S_n$ and "mit Affekt" means smaller Galois group. I also have no idea where this terminology comes from.

Comment: @Lukas Heger yes, I agree you are probably right. It is hard for me to remember what those two terms mean (like “inessential discriminant divisor” in algebraic number theory).